# Add users to item user field using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, display-template

I have a list with a multiple people column (name it **Members**).
I want to update item's column to add a user to it. But it have to keep all users already in the item's column. I want to do so using JavaScript.

So far, I have :

```
function addUser() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
    var listItem= list.getItemById(listItemID);

    var newMembers = oldMembers + newUser; 
    listItem.set_item('Members',newMembers);
    listItem.update();

    clientContext.load(listItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(console.log("ok."), console.log("ko."));
}
```

newUser contains id and loginName like: **1#;i:0#.f|membership|nameUser@domain.com**
In oldUser, i would like to have all user already in the field.
To do so, i wanted to use this:

```
var oldMembers = listItem.get_item("Members");
```

But I keep having this error:

> Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has
>   not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need
>   to be explicitly requested.

Is there another way to add my new user at the end of my old users list?

Environment : SharePoint Online. I'm working on a display template for a search web part only for this list. Users should be able in one click to join an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using REST API.

First : Use **Get** to know whose users are already in the Members field

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteDirectoryUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$filter=Title eq '" + title + "'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {

        //Action here
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("second here: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Second : Put the information in an array

```
var object = data.d.results;
var array = object[0].MembersId;
```

Third: Add current user to the array

```
array = object[0].MembersId.results;
array.push(userID); 

var dataInfos = {
    __metadata: {"type": "SP.Data.MyListListItem"},
    MembersId:{"results": array}
};
```

Fourth : Use **Patch** to update the Members field with the new user.

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteDirectoryUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" + listItemID + ")",
    method:"PATCH",
    data:JSON.stringify(dataInfos),
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "If-Match": "*"
    },

    success: function (data) {},
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

I did it to remove user too. Feel free to ask me for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where in code you are executing this line:

```
var oldMembers = listItem.get_item("Members");
```

You should try to call the `load` function before that line:

```
clientContext.load(listItem, 'Include(Members)');
```

EDIT:
You should also load the list after creating the list variable:

```
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
clientContext.load(list);
```

Comment: I was executing it just after getting listItem.

Comment: I tried but it did'nt work either.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.